# How to uninstall yii rights and user

Tags: database, netbeans, yii, yii-extensions

I installed yii user and rights successfully then i did some changes in my database and synchronize it , but now it is not working good, i want to remove this yii user and rights extension

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling an extension isn't a hard work in yii. **Just removing extension configuration from `config/main.php` can disable an extension.** But for completely remove user and rights extensions, you can do the following two works in addition to first step:

- Remove all related user and rights table form database
- Remove user and rights folder from extensions